# Check if daemon process is runnning

Tags: python, django, process, daemon

I am running several daemon processes, I need to maintain a log to check which all processes are running after a time interval of every 15 mins. Code I tried to implement is

```
def monitor_deamons():
   print "starting monitor"
   demo = ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep daemon #fails
   print demo
   PROCESSCOUNT=(ps -ef |grep -v grep |grep -cw <daemon name> #fails
   print PROCESSCOUNT
```

I am starting all these deamon threads by the following commands

```
python daemon_name.py start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post some code that successfully executes your first command, the result you store in `demo` and from it you may extrapolate how to get the `PROCESS_COUNT`.

```
import subprocess

def monitor_deamons():
   print "starting monitor"

   ps = subprocess.Popen(('ps', '-ef'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   grep = subprocess.Popen(('grep', '-v', 'grep'), stdin=ps.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

   ps.stdout.close()  # Allow ps to receive a SIGPIPE if grep exits.

   grep_daemon = subprocess.Popen(('grep', 'daemon'), stdin=grep.stdout)

   grep.stdout.close() # Allow grep to receive a SIGPIPE if grep_daemon exits

   output = grep_daemon.communicate()[0]

   print output

monitor_deamons()
```

Next time you run in to a problem explain what you have tried, and searched for. Had you investigated how to execute processes from Python you would have found subprocess. From there you could have googled how to pipe between processes in Python and arrived at a similar solution to mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `threading` module provided in python. If you run below commands in same process, this will give you more information on daemon threads created by your daemon_name.py process.

Get thread counts:

```
In [12]: threading.activeCount()
Out[12]: 26
```

List all active threads:

```
In [5]: threading.enumerate()
Out[5]: 
[<HistorySavingThread(IPythonHistorySavingThread, started 140361105082112)>,
 <Thread(Thread-17, started daemon 140359321511680)>,
 <Thread(Thread-9, started daemon 140359866775296)>,
 <Thread(Thread-22, started daemon 140359279548160)>,
 <Thread(Thread-5, started daemon 140360376239872)>,
 <Thread(Thread-18, started daemon 140359313118976)>,
 <Thread(Thread-10, started daemon 140359858382592)>,
 <Thread(Thread-20, started daemon 140359296333568)>,
 <Thread(Thread-21, started daemon 140359287940864)>,
 <Thread(Thread-13, started daemon 140359833204480)>,
 <Thread(Thread-16, started daemon 140359329904384)>,
 <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140361348196160)>,
 <Thread(Thread-19, started daemon 140359304726272)>]
```

Access any thread and perform any operations.

```
In [8]: t17 = threading.enumerate()[1]

In [9]: t17.
t17.daemon     t17.getName    t17.ident      t17.isAlive    t17.isDaemon   t17.is_alive   t17.join       t17.name       t17.run        t17.setDaemon  t17.setName    t17.start      

In [9]: t17.getName()
Out[9]: 'Thread-17'
```

I hope this helps.